# Is there a keyword that can make a class variable readonly from outside the class but not on the inside?

Tags: vb.net

Basically, the readonly keyword doesn't let me modify a field after I first create the class instance. I could use a property but in this case its just extra overhead. Is there a keyword to make a class field readonly from only outside the class?

Comment: The property is the way to go. The overhead is minimal.

Answer (score 1):

make the field private, provide getter and setter for it.
**Make the setter private.**
This way the value can be seen from outside the class by the getter,but, cannot be set/written  from outside the class.
this makes the property read-only from outside the class.

Answer (score 1):

As others have stated, use a property. If you don't want to split the property into one `Getter` and one `Setter` then make the setter private.

```
Public Class Foo

    Public Property Abc() As Object
        Get
            Return Me.m_Abc
        End Get
        Private Set(value As Object)
            Me.m_Abc = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private m_Abc As Object

End Class
```

However: The common way is to set the access level of the field to `Friend` making it accessible within the same assembly, but not from outside the assembly.

```
Public Class Foo

    Public ReadOnly Property Abc() As Object
        Get
            Return Me.m_Abc
        End Get
    End Property

    Friend m_Abc As Object

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

No there isn't. This type is scenario is precisely why properties are provided in the first place. You get a whole lot of flexibility.

However, if you insist you want to use a read only field, you can use reflection to change the value:-

```
Public Class TestClass

    Public ReadOnly MyNumber As Integer

    Public Sub New()
        'Readonly fields can only be changed this way
        'in the constructor
        Me.MyNumber = 900
    End Sub

    Public Sub ChangeNumber(ByVal num As Integer)
        SetNumber(num)
    End Sub

    Private Sub SetNumber(ByVal num As Integer)

        Dim fi = Me.GetType.GetField("MyNumber")

        'Reflection can change the value of
        'a read only field after construction
        fi.SetValue(Me, num)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Note that this is a very terrible thing. Reflection shouldn't be used for this sort of thing as you're going to take a performance hit. Just use properties and save yourself the trouble.